# wso2 6.6.0 - wso2carbon.log error after changing certificate

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 , Centos 7.8 , with mysql . I renew my certificate and trying to use it replace for my old one. This is what I did

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in newcert.crt -inkey mydomain.key -name "mydomain-2022" -out mydomain-2022.pfx
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mydomain-2022.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore 2022.jks -deststoretype JKS
keytool -export -alias "mydomain-2022" -keystore 2022.jks -file 2022.pem
keytool -import -alias mydomain-2022 -file 2022.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
find and replace all "2021.jks" with "2022.jks" on below files
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/conf/dashboard/deployment-mysql.yaml
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/conf/manager/deployment.yaml
vim /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.6.0/wso2/analytics/conf/worker/deployment.yaml
restart service
```

I can confirm that new certificate working - service is running - I can login to "https://esb.mydomain.com:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp" but my wso2carbon.log keep spawning these warning/error every minute

```
TID: [-1] [] [2022-10-12 21:03:12,351]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} - No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
TID: [-1] [] [2022-10-12 21:03:12,354] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:64)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:144)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
        ... 11 more
```

Please give me some advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a connection refused error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` when EI is trying to connect to the Analytics server. Hence I believe your Analytics server is not up and running. If you have started the Analytics server and it's not starting check the logs of the analytics server.

Comment: I don't really understand how El and Analytics server communication,I just following the guide to install WSO2 6.6.0 and use it, I have these files in /etc/init.d/
wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-dashboard  wso2ei-6.6.0-broker               wso2ei-6.6.0-integrator
wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-worker     wso2ei-6.6.0-business-process
but actually using wso2ei-6.6.0-integrator , wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-dashboard , wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-worker
I just 
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-integrator stop/start
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-worker stop/start
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-dashboard stop/start

Comment: @user36814 Did you try starting the ANalytics worker as you described above? If you do not need analytics you can disable that in EI configurations.

Comment: Yes I did
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-integrator stop/start
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-worker stop/start
/etc/init.d/wso2ei-6.6.0-analytics-dashboard stop/start

Answer (score 0):

Considering the above error and the comments, It seems you have enabled analytics on your WSO2-EI server.

**If you don't want to use analytics in your environment,**

- Set the property **mediation.flow.statistics.enable** to 'false' in the <EI_PRODUCT_PATH>/conf/synapse.properties file
- Restart the server.

**If you want to use analytics in your environment,**

- Set the property **mediation.flow.statistics.enable** to 'true' in the <EI_PRODUCT_PATH>/conf/synapse.properties file.
- Add the correct configurations of the analytics server to the <EI_PRODUCT_PATH>/conf/carbon.xml under the  element.
- Import the public key certificate of the Analytics server into the <EI_PRODUCT_PATH>/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks file of the EI Server.
- Restart the server.